# MySQL - Perform checks on groupings of records

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a result set like this:

```
"id","reference_id","type"
"1","aaa","A"
"2","aab","M"
"3","aac","A"
"4","aaa","M"
"5","aaa","E"
"6","aab","M"
"7","aac","M"
"8","aab","D"
"9","aac","M"
```

I want to run some validations on it using sql.

- Each reference_id life cycle must contain only one "A";
- Each reference_id life cycle must conatin at least 1 "E" and/or 1 "D";

How can I iterate through a resultset and perform checks per group of records (reference_id).

Comment: Each reference_id life cycle must contain only one "A"; --- exactly one A or less than 2 A?

Comment: @ Xie - Exactly 1 "A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated) Try:

```
select r.* 
from my_result_set r
join (select reference_id
      from my_result_set
      group by reference_id
      having sum(case type when 'A' then 1 end) = 1 and
             sum(case when type in ('D','E') then 1 end) >= 1) s
  on r.reference_id = s.reference_id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b48af/14).

Comment: This returns all the "good" reference_id's. When doing validation, one probably wants to find the non-validating ones.

Comment: Mark, I thought this did the job and it sort of does except for the fact that it groups the result and I need it to stay ungrouped.

Comment: @Mark: Beautiful, simple, does the job. Thx.